# Custom Data Import not showing in Google Analytic Reports

Tags: csv, google-analytics, analytics

How is my data supposed to display in the Reports when I upload custom data through Data Import in Google Analytic?

I'm uploading a csv sheet with User Id values and a second value with the number of followers a particular User Id has created in my app. The csv sheet is uploaded successfully in Data Import. My data set type is User. I'm using User Id as key and Supporters Added as imported data value. However, this data does not show up anywhere in the reports. I am able to view User Ids but not the amount of followers that user created.

Am I missing a step in Custom Data importing with Google Analytic? Where should this data be displayed in the reports?

Comment: 1. Is "Supporters Added" a custom metric?
2. Are you using [query time data import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6071511)?
3. Are you looking for historic values or future values?

Comment: Hi @Matt, I'm actually using Supporters Added as a custom dimension that I select when creating the values within Google Analytics for data import from csv. When I created the Data Import schema I was not asked to set Query Time.  I would prefer to have the custom data be applied to historic values, as well as apply it to values created daily. Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To apply data import to historic data you need to use [Query Time data import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6071511), standard data import only affects future data about the customer.